# Want to achieve this kind of functionality in iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am having an app in which I want my view to be loaded like shown in the screen shot below.

The following view contains page control to show multiple images,buttons,labels,resizable text view and resizable text field in a single cell of table view.

There will be number of rows in a table view and rows will be generated dynamically.

Is there any cocoa control or tool which can give me functionality like this?

I have searched on cocoa control and goggled it a lot but couldn't find any matches to achieve this.

I thought of taking different views with sub viewing it didn't get much idea of how to generate it dynamically.

Please help me if someone has achieved this kind of functionality in any of their projects.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Don't make the Questions duplicate **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420990/how-to-achieve-the-following-ui** instead of edit your question. So that, we can vote up for reOpen. and also check **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask**,

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

Divide each items in cells for single section,  that means, one section for one item.

for e.g.

- User photo, User name, User location and Post time in one cell.
- Image gallery in another cell with page control on it.
- Favourite (liked) post, comment on post and price in individual cells.

what you've to do is, create and add each item in a cell. While you're giving the height of each cell using delegate, check for conditions for which you're assigning the height. For e.g. if you've likes for the post (favourite) then only give height for that cell otherwise pass 0 (zero). Do the same for everything or as per your requirement.

For comments, you've to calculate text height, and based on that, you'll need to set height for comment cell.

References:

Here's a nice tutorial for this (not exactly) stuff. [Rebuilding Instagram Feed Table View](http://engineering.2359media.net/blog/2014/04/16/rebuilding-instagram-feed-table-view/). I also googled a lot and found this, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stxdynamictableview, you may also need https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mhpagingscrollview for showing image gallery.

P.S. This is not a "lunch plate" of course you've to make it for your self. Get hands on the keyboard! :)

Good luck!